AWS S3N Commands in AWS CLI
I want to test my access to a s3n bucket called s3n://example-folder/example_file_2024
I have never used s3n before and although I've done some searches over the internet and understood the purpose of it, I couldn't find an example on AWS CLI commands to access it.
Can someone help on this?
Invalid bucket name "s3n:":

Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,255}$" or be an
ARN matching the regex
"^arn:(aws).:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z-0-9]:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}$"

So far I have been trying to run aws s3 ls s3n://example-folder/example_file_2024 but this gives me the error below and I'm not sure if this command can be used with s3n or only s3. Also if I look into the S3 buckets in my AWS role it does not appear there under general purpose buckets but again not sure if there's where I should be looking into.

The s3n prefix relates to how a local file system driver accesses the content in S3. The bucket itself is not an s3n bucket. Use the actual bucket name and access the contents via the s3n driver.
